# How to run a while loop to run a dynamic query in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to run a while loop to run a dynamic query in SQL?

```
Declare @var1 nvarchar(max)
Declare @var2 nvarchar(max)
Declare @var3 nvarchar(max)

While loop ( @var1, @var2, @var3 .... )
 Begin  
     insert into TableA
     exec (@var1) .. - in the loop logic
 End
```

Comment: You may refer [while loops in sql-server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Yeah , but passing the variable & running  the exec var1 .. exec @var2 in the sequence ..

Comment: This is a dynamic query execution, not just while loop .. I need to fetch each variables to the exec syntax

Comment: do you want to iterate through the list of variables?

Comment: Yes please.. fetch each variable & pass it to the exec syntax inside the loop

Comment: I guess , I need to have a static variable which receives the input value & execute the syntax

Comment: You can't iterate through the variables. What you can do is to insert this variables into the temp table and then do while loop or even better pass the table variable with all this values to the procedure and then do everything there

Comment: Okay iteration part is clear. Second question is passing each variable to the exec syntax. Do I need to have a temp variable holder??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, you wan to use a loop to execute a set of dynamic SQL queries. Then you need to use a table to iterate between them,
Im using a variable table, but you can use a temp table if you prefer

```
DECLARE @Vars TABLE([ID] NOT NULL IDENTITY, [Var] NVARCHAR(MAX))
/*
INSERT Values to @Vars
*/
DECLARE @ID INT, @Var NVARCHAR(MAX)
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Vars)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @ID = [ID], @Var = [Var] FROM @Vars ORDER BY [ID]

    INSERT TableA
    EXEC(@Var)

    DELETE @Vars WHERE [ID] = @ID
END
```